# Excel to MySQL Connection and SQLExecute for multiple users

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I need to develop an excel based spreadsheet used by all of our employees to capture time-sheet and other project related data.  These employees have a range of Microsoft Office Excel versions.  My plan is to use MySQL Server (not MS SQL) to capture the info from these spreadsheets each time it updates or is saved.

### Problem:

The original system is an excel based system which is getting too big.  This new system must be implemented in parallel and eliminate bulky as we go along until we have a complete new system everyone understands (i.e. implementing new stuff bit by bit).

### Question:

1. Is there a way to do this without VBA and live?  If not then I need the code to execute when the spreadsheet is saved.  The code must take values from the spreadsheet and write it to a specific field in the database table (INSERT INTO or UPDATE sql statements).
2. What is the easiest way to implement this (without having to install anything on all of the employee's computers i.e. having this spreadsheet run as-developed)?
3. I need to be able to extract this info for processing on a "management" spreadsheet (i.e. import the latest info captured from the MySQL database tables).  What do I need to do (I can use VBA here) - Statement such as Select * from table_timesheets.
4. Without then compromising privileged information (such as salary expenses), I need to have many employees/project managers view the value of their individual projects on a new spreadsheet.  (I think if I understand point 3 I would be able to do this one).

### Info:

MySQL Version:  5.1.73
Database will be located on a local network server on a Windows based machine.
Internal network IP address is fixed.

Any suggestions please.